# Convergence of series depending on convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a convergent series of positive terms $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ and have to check if series
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{\log(n)}\left(n^{a_n}-1\right)$$ converges.
I think it does, but don't know how to prove that, I tried using Cauchy criterion, but couldn't really make it work.